# How do you align other views with a UITableViewCell's textLabel?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have created a text label for my `table.tableHeaderView` and I want it to left align the same as the text in my standard `UITableViewCell.textLabel`. How do I get the correct X offset?

The `cell.indentationWidth` is 10 and the `cell.indentationLevel = 0` but that's clearly not the whole story. In both the `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` and `willDisplayCell:` tableView methods the X origin of the `UITableViewCell.textLabel` is 0.

Can I determine the X origin of the `cell.textLabel` ahead of time? Or do I have to get it and then find the origin relative to the tableView and then update the X origin of my headerLabel?

Download [sample project](http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=03065246721631766064) here.

```
@implementation ViewController {
    UILabel *headerTextLabel;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self.tableView registerClass:[UITableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"myId"];

    CGRect headerFrame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.tableView.bounds.size.width, 100); // arbitrary height
    UIView *header = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:headerFrame];
    header.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
    self.tableView.tableHeaderView = header;

    CGFloat xHeaderLabel = 0; // What do I set this to?

    // header text label should be left-aligned and match the cell text
    headerTextLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(xHeaderLabel, 0, 300, 40)]; // arbitrary header size
    headerTextLabel.text = @"Header text -- align with cells";
    headerTextLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
    [header addSubview:headerTextLabel];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"myId"];
    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Cell %ld", (long)indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    return cell;
}


- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    cell.textLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 5;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the separator inset on `UITableView`:

```
 NSLog(self.tableView.separatorInset.left);  // -> 15.0
```

Comment: This should line you up with the cell's `contentView`, there is probably some default padding added to the left edge.  Coloring the contentView's background would show this visually.  There's no great way to get this value without hard-coding, short of having your first cell tell the header where it should be lined up.

Comment: The separatorInset.left doesn't appear to align up with the contentView. (Content view is green -> http://i.imgur.com/oWKpza9.png) That means the padding is inside the contentView? I'd rather have the first cell tell the header than hardcode, but as I mentioned in the question the textLabel's x origin appears to be 0.

Comment: None of the frames are valid inside of cellForRowAtIndexPath. You have to force a layout (`setNeedsLayout`) or use your own cell subclass so you have full control.  None of this is particularly pretty :).